# Gcloud API file.save() data format

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I'm using the gcloud API on a Nodejs web server to upload files. I'd prefer the files not be uploaded on the client side and instead uploaded on the server. Currently, I am producing a blob on the client side, then converting it to text and passing that to the server through a POST request. All of the information gets successfully passed from the client to the server as expected. This data is also uploaded to gcloud, however, Gcloud does not recognize this as a valid file nor does my computer when I download it.

What is the best way to get the contents of the file to gcloud from the server side? I've tried using dataURIs and reading the orignal file by text and both produce similiar issues. I've also explored piping a readFileStream from the blob on the server end but blobs are not natively supported by node so I have not done so yet.

**Client Side**

```
function readSingleFile(e, func, func2){
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if(!file){
    return; // Add error msg_here
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e){
    let contents = e.target.result;
    let img = document.createElement('img')
    let cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
    img.onload = ()=>{
      cvs.width = img.width;
      cvs.height= img.height;
      let ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      cvs.toBlob((res)=>{res.text().then((text)=>{func2(text)})}, "image/jpeg", 0.92);
    }
    img.src=contents;
    func(contents);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

**Server Side**

```
function publishPrintjob(dataObj){
  try{
  var newElemKey = database.ref().child('queue').push().key; // Get random Key
  // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
  const gcloudFile = storage.file('images/' + newElemKey + '.jpg');
  gcloudFile.save(dataObj.sockImageFile, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      Console.log("File Uploaded!")
    }
  });

  var data = {
    date: dataObj.Date,
    email: dataObj.email,
    design: dataObj.Design,
    author: dataObj.Author,
    address: dataObj.address,
    imageKey: newElemKey,
  }

  admin.database().ref('queue/' + newElemKey).set(data);
} catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}

}
```

Note: func simply shows the image on the client side, func2 just adds the contents to the POST object.

Comment: Try using `storage.bucket(bucketName).upload()` instead: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs . See the code here also: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/using-cloud-storage#application_code

Comment: upload doesn't work because the file is being uploaded from the server not the client. I ended up instead writing a quick script that converts a URI back to an image blob on the server and then piped the readStream to a writeStream from Gcloud.

Comment: Great that you solved it. Could you share the solution in an answer, so the community can benefit from it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file directly from the computer would be easiest using the `storage.bucket(bucketName).upload()` function from the cloud storage library. However, this uses location of a file locally and thus will not work unless a file is transferred to the server and saved first. This could be achieved using multi-part form data. Using multipart or uploading locally are better methods for uploading to google storage.

Instead, I solve this by first converting the image to a dataURI, sending the data URI to the server via the body of a GET request, and then converting it to a buffer with a readable stream that can be piped to google storage.

**Client**

```
  let formData = getFormData('myForm');


  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
      }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "dashboard", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
  xhttp.onload = ()=> {
    console.log(JSON.parse(xhttp.response))
    // Handle server response here
  };
}
```

**Server**

```
// DataObject is the body of the GET request, the property imageFile is the URI from readFileAsURI
    function uploadImageOnServer(dataObj){
      try{
      var newElemKey = database.ref().child('queue').push().key; // Get random Key to use as filename

      // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
      const gcloudFile = storage.file('images/' + newElemKey + '.jpeg');
    
    
      var fs = require('fs'); // Should be required at the top of the file
      var string = dataObj.ImageFile; 
      var regex = /^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/;
    
      var matches = string.match(regex);
      var ext = matches[1];
      var data = matches[2];
      var buffer = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
    
      // Create the readstream
      const readableInstanceStream = new Readable({
            read() {
              this.push(buffer);
              this.push(null);
            }
          });
          readableInstanceStream.pipe(gcloudFile.createWriteStream()) // link to gcloud storage api
          .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('error')
          })
          .on('finish', function() {
            console.log('upload complete')
          });
    } catch(err){
      console.log(err)
    }
    
    }
```